# When using Twitter Bootstrap in IFrame IE thinks it has overflow

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

We're using version 1.3 of Bootstrap. We're popping up an IFrame from this div:

```
<div id="searchDialog" class="modal hide" title="Search">

    <div class="modal-header" style="left:40%">
       <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
       <h3>Search</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe style="width: 700px; height: 400px; overflow: auto; border-style: none" src="<c:url value="/kb/workgroup/usersearch"/>"></iframe>
     </div>

</div>
```

In the JSP that is involked (via Spring MVC) it has the bootstrap css reference:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/skins/kb/css/bootstrap.css" />" />
```

The IFrame works fine with Firefox but IE 8 has a vertical scroll bar but no extra content to scroll. When I remove the bootstrap css reference the vertical scrollbar disappears.

So I'm thinking bootstrap's need for 960px might confuse ... or something similar.

Also with the bootstrap css reference in there when I try to use bootstrap row and span classes the effect is odd i.e., is not working properly.

Any thoughts? (Hard for us to upgrade bootstrap at this point). Can I expect to use Bootstrap within an IFrame? I've looked unsuccessfully for examples. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use an ajax request to put the contents of /kb/workgroup/usersearch in the modal?

Comment: Yes thanks good idea. A little more work though.

Comment: (Changing existing code in a schedule).